# $g:\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ and $g(m, n) = m^2 − n ^2$. Is this proof valid

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Determine whether or not g is surjective.
Would this be a valid proof?

If we take any $y$, and set $m=0$. Then we have the equation $y = 0 - n^2$ and solve for $n$.

Then we'll have the $\sqrt{y} = n$. If $y = 2$ then $n = \sqrt{2}$, which does not belong to the codomain therefore the function is not surjective.

Comment: Is the problem to determine whether or not $g$ is surjective?

Comment: yes it's to determine whether or not g is surjective

Comment: I've added the solution-verification tag.

Comment: Not,  that only prove there is no solution to $f(0,n) = 2$ but maybe there is a solution where $m \ne 0$.

Comment: One hint  $f(n,m) = m^2 - n^2 = (m-n)(m+n)$.  Is there any number that is *not* in that form? Can you prove that every number is of that form?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete proof.

To determine that a function $g\colon \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ is not surjective, you need to find an integer $a$ for which $g(m,n)$ has no solution, where $m$ and $n$ are allowed to be any integer. You've shown that there are some $a$ for which there is no solution with $m=0$, or with $n=0$, but this doesn't cover all pairs of integers.

To give a hint towards a full solution, consider the equation $m^2-n^2=2$. Can you show that there is no pair $(m,n)$ of integers satisfying this equation? This will show that $2$ is not in the image of $g$, and so $g$ is not surjective.

Comment: yes no pair of integers f: (m,n) will equal 2 so it's not surjective

Comment: "yes no pair of integers f: (m,n) will equal 2"  How do you know that?  You *have* to show that.   It's not enough to assume it is true.

Answer (score 0):

No, your proof is not valid, as commented by fleablood.

And his hint may developped as follows:

$g(m,n)=(m-n)(m+n)$ hence:

- if $m,n$ are of the same parity then $4\mid g(m,n);$
- else, $g(m,n)$ is odd.

Therefore, $g$ is not surjective. Its image even contains *none* of the integers $\equiv2\bmod4.$